# How to concat one column of multiple rows (group by clause used in query)

Tags: sql-server, group-by, group-concatenation

I had some issue while populating some data as per my requirements and that is as follows..

**Table data:**

```
---------------------------------------------
EMPID  PROJ_TYPE  HOURS  ST_DATE    ED_DATE
---------------------------------------------
1      DEV        10     2013-1-1   2013-5-1
1      DEV        34     2013-5-2   2013-8-1
1      DEV        23     2013-8-2   2013-10-1
1      TEST       12     2014-1-1   2014-3-1
1      TEST       25     2014-3-2   2014-6-1
```

Here I want to fetch the employee data with hours, So as simple I wrote

```
SELECT EMPID,
       PROJ_TYPE, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PROJ_TYPE='DEV' THEN HOURS ELSE 0 END) DEV, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PROJ_TYPE='TEST' THEN HOURS ELSE 0 END) TEST
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY EMPID, PROJ_TYPE
```

Hence it is returning two rows as expected but here the twist I want only one row per employee. If employee have multiple `PROJ_TYPE` then it should combine both project values and return only one row.

Finally my result set should look like:

```
----------------------------
EMPID  PROJ     DEV  TEST
----------------------------
1     DEV/TEST  67   37
```

Hope I am clear please comment if any doubt on my question.

Comment: please add a dbfiddle so we can try our code: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 1):

A pivot will work for this

**Test Data:**

```
Declare @Test Table
(
 EMPID          Int
,PROJ_TYPE      NVarchar(4)
,HOURS          Int
,ST_DATE        Date
,ED_DATE        Date
);
Insert Into @Test
(EMPID, PROJ_TYPE, HOURS, ST_DATE, ED_DATE)
Values ('1', 'DEV','10','2013-1-1','2013-5-1')
        ,('1', 'DEV','34','2013-5-2','2013-8-1')
        ,('1', 'DEV','23','2013-8-2','2013-10-1')
        ,('1', 'TEST','12','2014-1-1','2014-3-1')
        ,('1', 'TEST','25','2014-3-2','2014-6-1')
        ,('2', 'DEV','7','2013-5-2','2013-8-1')
        ,('2', 'DEV','14','2013-8-2','2013-10-1')
        ,('2', 'TEST','12','2014-1-1','2014-3-1')
        ,('2', 'TEST','19','2014-3-2','2014-6-1')
        ,('3', 'DEV','34','2013-5-2','2013-8-1')
        ,('3', 'DEV','8','2013-8-2','2013-10-1')
        ,('3', 'TEST','12','2014-1-1','2014-3-1')
        ,('3', 'TEST','7','2014-3-2','2014-6-1')
        ,('3', 'DEV','23','2013-8-2','2013-10-1')
        ,('3', 'TEST','18','2014-1-1','2014-3-1')
        ,('4', 'TEST','25','2014-3-2','2014-6-1');
```

**Query:**

```
Select      EMPID
            ,IsNull(DEV,0) As DEV
            ,IsNull(TEST,0) As TEST
From        (
            Select      EMPID
                        ,PROJ_TYPE
                        ,HOURS
            From        @Test
            ) sq
    Pivot   (
            Sum(HOURS)
            For PROJ_TYPE In ([DEV],[TEST])
            ) piv;
```

**SQL Fiddle:** 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d9a0ceb9dbf13e8af351822733c4607

Answer (score 0):

Just don't group by project type (nor select it without a grouping function)

```
SELECT EMPID,         
       TOTAL_HOURS = SUM(HOURS), -- Just for cross-check
       PROJ = CASE WHEN SELECT (COUNT (DISTINCT PROJ_TYPE) 
                        FROM TABLE1 E 
                        WHERE E.EMPID = EE.EMPID 
                        GROUP BY E.EMPID) > 1 
                   THEN 'DEV/TEST' 
                   ELSE SELECT (DISTINCT PROJ_TYPE 
                                FROM TABLE1 TE 
                                WHERE TE.EMPID = EE.EMPID 
                                GROUP BY E.EMPID) 
              END,
     SUM(CASE WHEN PROJ_TYPE='DEV' THEN HOURS ELSE 0 END) AS DEV, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN PROJ_TYPE='TEST' THEN HOURS ELSE 0 END) AS TEST
FROM TABLE1 EE
GROUP BY EMPID
```

It's not elegant but should work

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* this:

```
    with cte as (select EMPID,PROJ_TYPE, SUM(CASE WHEN PROJ_TYPE='DEV' THEN HOURS ELSE 0 END) DEV, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN PROJ_TYPE='TEST' THEN HOURS ELSE 0 END) TEST
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY EMPID, PROJ_TYPE)

    select t1.empID, isnull(t1.proj,'') + '/' + isnull(t2.proj,'') as proj, t1.hours, t2.hours)
    from cte t1
    full outer join cte t2 on t1.empID = t2.empID
    where isnull(t1.proj,'Dev') = 'Dev'
    and isnull(t2.proj, 'Test') = 'Test'
```